# How to get everything between two tags if the closing tag appears in the parent?

Tags: php, screen-scraping

This is the problem: The script I use stops looking at the first tag.

I'm sceaping a website, and this is the part of the site I want to 'extract'.

```
<div class="i-want-this-div">
    <div class="annoying-sub-div">
        Bla bla bla  
    </div>
    <div class="annoying-sub-div">
        etc...
    </div>
    <div class="annoying-sub-div">
    </div>
    <div class="annoying-sub-div">
    </div>
    <div class="annoying-sub-div">
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to display all those 'annoying'(because they mess up the function of the script by being there) divs  on my site, but how do I do this?

This is my current approach: get the position of the first tag, get the position of the closing  tag and subtract that part form the entire string that holds the whole website source.

```
$startPos     = strpos($siteIAmScreaping, '<div class="i-want-this-div">');
$endPos       = strpos($siteIAmScreaping, '</div>', $startPos) + 8;
$annoyingDivs = substr($siteIAmScreaping, $startPos, $endPos-$startPos);
```

The problem is: I want it to stop on the main divs closing tag and not on the first closing tag it finds.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use [querypath](/questions/tagged/querypath) (or [phpquery](/questions/tagged/phpquery)) for simplicity. You can then extract the `<div>` content by class or id most easily:

```
 print htmlqp($page)->find("div.i-want-this-div")->html();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) for stuff like this.

Comment: Could you explain a bit? how do I get everything between the div.i-want-this-div tags?

Answer (score -1):

Are you saying to want to show the actual code?  If so put your code inside the pre tags.

```
<pre></pre>
```

Everything within will remail formatted and all tags/code will be visible.

Comment: I want to extract only a piece of another site.